# Flutter pop up menu item hides button

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When I tap the pop up menu button the pop up menu item hides the button itself:

```
        SizedBox(
          width: 60,
          height: 60,
          child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            icon: const ProfilePictureCard(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return {'Profile', 'Logout'}.map((String choice) {
                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
        ),
```

The items need to below the actual button. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you are planning to close the popUp menu

Comment: Haven't planned yet tbh

Comment: I think you should think about it first

Comment: I dont understand. Can you explain it please?

Comment: When you tap on button, It close, this is the general case. If you can stop this behavior how do you like to close it

Comment: I am not trying to change the behavior I just need to show the Profile and Logout options a bit lower than the button. So that the button is always visible. And the answer provided by syafuan works.

Comment: You can upvote his answer on that case, and *do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive.* Check more about [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `offset: Offset(0, 60)` in your PopupMenuButton property, 60 indicate your SizedBox's height, so the menu will move below the button

```dart
        SizedBox(
          width: 60,
          height: 60,
          child: PopupMenuButton<String>(
            offset: Offset(0, 60), ///here
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            icon: const ProfilePictureCard(),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return {'Profile', 'Logout'}.map((String choice) {
                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Popupmenubutton has a position property. Just set it to 'under' (it is an enum). This is a better way of doing it instead of using offset which you will have to hardcode.

e.g

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
        position: PopupMenuPosition.under,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        icon: const ProfilePictureCard(),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
          return {'Profile', 'Logout'}.map((String choice) {
            return PopupMenuItem<String>(
              value: choice,
              child: Text(choice),
            );
          }).toList();
        },
      )
```